# How do I prevent the second \subsubsection in my document being indented

Tags: sectioning, indentation

The problem I'm having is that my second subsubsection is being indented. Probably something which is being done automatically. However, I'm new to LaTeX and don't have a clue how to fix it, so can someone please tell me how to. Below I have reproduced the problem but removed the text I wrote. I know the formatting might look a bit weird on the first page(the footnote), but it's okay with the original text I have so please ignore that.

To clarify: I want NO indention on the second subsubsection which has the text "Brief History of Computer Simulation". Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\section*{Simulation Techniques}
\end{center}

\vspace*{12mm}
\subsubsection*{Introduction}
\vspace*{2mm}

Text bla bla text here bla bla

\begin{center}
"bla bla" 
\footnote{url bla bla}
\end{center}

\noindent More text here bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\noindent bla bla bla even more text \pagebreak
%---------------Page 2------------------
\subsubsection*{ Brief History of Computer Simulation}
\vspace*{3mm}
The first..
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, If you see anything that you discourage or anything that might cause me problems in the future please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: There are many things I wouldn't recommend: explicit spacings should be avoided as much as possible. Look at the `titlesec` package for redefining section titles so that just `\section` will give centering and the desired spacings. However, the problem seems to be in the space between the brace and the "B".

Comment: Yes I just realised. Should've had a closer look! But thanks for the reference. Will definitely have a look.

Comment: One more question, how do I make the top section appear further up the page i.e. making the padded space at the top margin less, as I feel the section stands quite low on the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppress the spurious blank space; instead of

```
\subsubsection*{ Brief History of Computer Simulation}
```

use

```
\subsubsection*{Brief History of Computer Simulation}
```

Also, to format the sectional units, you can use the  [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to avoid manual changes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{4.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{3.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
  {0pt}{4.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\section*{Simulation Techniques}

\subsubsection*{Introduction}

Text bla bla text here bla bla

\begin{center}
"bla bla" 
\footnote{url bla bla}
\end{center}

\noindent More text here bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\noindent bla bla bla even more text \pagebreak

\subsubsection*{ Brief History of Computer Simulation}

The first..
\end{document}
```

If you want to suppress the paragraph indentation for all the document, you can consider using the [`parskip`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package:

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```

or switching to the `scrartcl` document class from the KOMA-Script bundle and using one of the `parskip` options it provides; i.e.,

```
\documentclass[parskip=half+]{scrartcl}
```

Comment: Oh god. How did I miss that. Sorry for such a trivial error. I'm completely new to this.

Comment: @Jatt I've added some more recommendations to my answer.